# In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file

Tags: codeigniter

I am in the process of upgrading codeigniter from 1.7.2 to 2.0.1.

Everything seems to have gone ok except I get

> In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.

What is the change in 2.0.0/2.0.1 that has caused this?

What change do I need to make to fix this.

Will making said change break anything?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ohai again https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html :D

The reason they ask for an encryption key is security (obviously)

*Note: Even if you are not using encrypted sessions, you must set an encryption key in your config file which is used to aid in preventing session data manipulation.* - source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

This modification won't break your code. But be careful when updating from 1.7.2 to 2.0.1. I suggest you to backup your code :)

BTW they added this security improvement with the 2.0.0 version of CI. I don't know why they don't mention it in their upgrade guide though :(

Comment: OH hello again, You look oddly familiar! it's strange that the need for an encryption key was not specified in the upgrade guide that you so kindly linked me to ;D

Comment: yeah that's weird, but I'm not a CI-guy so I wasn't aware of that encryption key :D

Comment: Just an avid google'r? And yeah, I have backed up my code, Just trying to get everything up and running as fast as possible, broken code = `>:|` boss!

Comment: I'm a Kohana user... A long time ago, it was very close to CI. And they still have some things in common ;)

Answer (score 21):

add this  to your config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'your_encryption_key_here';
```

Comment: what is defined here in place of your_encryption_key_here?

Answer (score 3):

./application/config/config.php

Encryption Key
  ---------------------

If you use the Encryption class or the Session class you
   MUST set an encryption key.  See the user guide for info.

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '02527-269-2503946-70386-34730519';
```