# Encryption key while using Session Class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When I auto-load session library from autoload.php in Codeigniter, following error is displayed in browser:
"In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file."

How to resolve this ?

Comment: this looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385524/in-order-to-use-the-session-class-you-are-required-to-set-an-encryption-key-in-y

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config.php

search for this

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
```

and change it to

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'something';
```

where something is an encryption key of your choice